# C# use static class properties as if they were namespaced?

Tags: c#, namespaces, using

I am trying to create a class to hold all my global constants, e.g.:

```
namespace MyProj
{
    public static class Constants
    {
        public const string MY_STRING = "this needs to be used ad nauseum";
    }
}
```

This works great.  However, the result is that in code I have to always type:

```
doSomethingWith(Constants.MY_STRING);
```

When what I really want to be able to do is go (something like):

```
using MyProj.Constants;
doSomethingWith(MY_STRING);
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `static` to your `using`:

```
using static MyProj.Constants;
```

Details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static).

Comment: Learn something new every day !